# Why do boost asio awaitable operators swallow exceptions?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

After watching this excellent talk [Talking Async](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icgnqFM-aY4) I am experimenting with boost asio awaitable operators for cancellation and timeouts with C++ 20 coroutines.

While this works, I do not understand the error handling.

The following program runs without an error message, whereas I would expect the output "for testing".

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace io = boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

io::awaitable<void> Cancelled(io::steady_timer& cancelTimer)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    co_await cancelTimer.async_wait(io::redirect_error(io::use_awaitable, ec));
}

io::awaitable<void> Throws(io::io_context& context)
{
    io::steady_timer timer{ context, 100ms };
    co_await timer.async_wait(io::use_awaitable);
    throw std::runtime_error("for testing");
}

io::awaitable<void> Run(io::io_context& context, io::steady_timer& cancelTimer)
{
    co_await (Throws(context) || Cancelled(cancelTimer));
}

void RethrowException(std::exception_ptr e)
{
    if (e)
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(e);
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        io::io_context context;
        io::steady_timer cancelTimer{ context, 200ms };

        io::co_spawn(context, Run(context, cancelTimer), RethrowException);

        context.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Modifying the code like

```cpp
io::awaitable<void> Run(io::io_context& context, io::steady_timer& cancelTimer)
{
    co_await Throws(context);
}
```

behaves like expected. I could reproduce this on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) using the latest MSVC compiler (x64 msvc v19.latest) and boost library (vcpkg 2022.05.10).

So how am I going to do error handling with awaitable operators?

Comment: Side note: std::exception does not [have that constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It has in MSVC ;-) Changing the code to std::runtime_error did not change the behaviour.

Comment: I looked at some of the source code, and I don't see an `||` overload for awaitables. So how does `Throws(context) || Cancelled(cancelTimer)` compile, and what exactly do you expect it to do?

Comment: Please note the #include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp> and see e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp20/coroutines/timeout.cpp or the "Talk Async" I linked. I expect that co_await returns if any of the awaitables passed to operator || completes and the other is cancelled. This happens, but the exception is swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of boost asio's `operator||()` for awaitables seems to be intended. Here is the code for one of the overloads of `operator||()` for awaitables from boost asio:

```cpp
/// Wait for one operation to succeed.
/**
 * If one operations succeeds, the other is cancelled as the OR-condition is
 * already satisfied.
 */
template <typename T, typename U, typename Executor>
awaitable<std::variant<T, U>, Executor> operator||(
    awaitable<T, Executor> t, awaitable<U, Executor> u)
{
    auto ex = co_await this_coro::executor;

    auto [order, ex0, r0, ex1, r1] =
        co_await make_parallel_group(
        co_spawn(ex, detail::awaitable_wrap(std::move(t)), deferred),
        co_spawn(ex, detail::awaitable_wrap(std::move(u)), deferred)
        ).async_wait(
        wait_for_one_success(),
        use_awaitable_t<Executor>{}
    );

    // ... //
}
```

The parameter `wait_for_one_success()` of the call to `make_parallel_group()` defines the behaviour such that the operator only returns, if any of the awaitables succeeds. If one fails by throwing an exception, the operator does not return.

The following hack modifies this behaviour:

```cpp
#include <boost\asio\experimental\cancellation_condition.hpp>
#define wait_for_one_success wait_for_one
#include <boost\asio\experimental\awaitable_operators.hpp>
#undef wait_for_on_success
```

Now an exception from one of the awaitables is propagated, which is the behaviour I would have expected in the first place.